# Django - Can´t show images | Problem with static folder setting

Tags: django

I have created a Static folder with img folder. It has a image: dog.jpg

euskaraz>euskaraz>static>img>dog.jpg

[image]

HTML template:

```
{% load static %}
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
            <img src="{% static 'img/dog.jpg' %}">
     </body>
   </html>
```

settings.py

[image]

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Inspecting element:

[image]

All project:

[image]

Where is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Open your site and click "inspect element" check what's written in the href, this might help you to understand where Django is looking for your file. Please don't use images for code.

Comment: inspecting element: <img src="/static/img/dog.jpg">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add your extra static directory to [**`STATICFILES_DIRS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) settings

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ("some_cool_name", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'euskaraz/static')),
]
```

then, in your template,

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% static 'some_cool_name/img/dog.jpg' %}">
```

Comment: I have tried what you comment, but it does not show the image. Thank you. euskaraz is project name.

Comment: add your *complete* project structure

Comment: Ok, now, you can see complete project. Thanks.

Comment: Excellet! I can see the image. Thank´s for all Arakkal Abu. ; )